# Set umlauts keyboard shortcuts with gsettings in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I want to set umlauts keyboard shortcuts in ubuntu 20.04. I tried the following without success.

```bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ name 'ä'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ command 'xdotool key adiaeresis'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom/ binding '<Alt>a'
```

If I try the command `xdotool key adiaeresis` in the terminal it results in the desired letter ä. Switchting the command to open a program the keyboard shortcuts works. I think the problem lies in the combination gsettings and xdotools.

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks, Johannes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to trigger the shortcut key, xdotool at the same time sends the adiaeresis to the keyboard. The system sees <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>ä</kbd>, so that is something not recognized.

You will need to introduce a delay before xdotool presses the adiaeresis, a delay long enough for you to release your shortcut key. In case of `xdotool`, you could also experiment with `keyup` in order to have `xdotool` release <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> before you physically release these keys (and send these keyup signals again).

*Note*: "in case of xdotool": this option is not possible if using `ydotool` (which also works under Wayland), because `ydotool` simulates input from a second, independent keyboard.

*Remark*: using a keyboard layout with dead keys may be an easier and more reliable approach to enter characters with umlauts (and accents, etc) using a standard US keyboard.